# ScrollHeight values are different in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to apply a class to div if the element is overflown. For this i compare the ScrollHeight  with ClientHeight. It works fine on chrome but not in IE. Below is the code snippet:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.assign_overflow();
}

assign_overflow = () => {
    const element = this.title_ref.current;
    element.classList.toggle('overflowing', element.scrollHeight > 
    element.clientHeight);
};

<div>
    <h5 ref={this.title_ref}>header</h5>
</div>

.overflowing::after {
    content: "...";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

In IE i see class "overflowing" applied to the element even though it should not be.Also in chrome i get the scrollheight value to be 20 and in IE it is 22. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: What version of IE are you running?

Comment: Try adding this : `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` meta-tag into your `<head>`.

Comment: Internet explorer version 11